# Print different results for different "checkbox" in PHP

Tags: php, html, checkbox, foreach, isset

Im doing an assignment and I got stuck.

I am preparing a project divided in 5 different .php files. The first page is an introduction page, where the user can type name and get started. 3 middle pages are for tests and quiz. The 5th and last page is a summary of the results of the previous tests. The second test is an <input type="checkbox" ...> and, according to the answer given, I want to print different results.

- If the 2 answers are correct echo= "Correct"
- If only 1 of the answers is correct echo= ""One of the two answers is wrong"
- If only 1 box was checked echo= "Answer is incomplete"
- No box was checked echo= "You did not select any option"
  This is the HTML

```
<p>Through mixing which of the following primary colors can the secondary color in the figure be obtained?</p>
<form action="quiz_3.php" method="POST">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="result_quiz_2[]" value="yellow">Yellow</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="result_quiz_2[]" value="red">Red</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="result_quiz_2[]" value="blue">Blue</label>
  
<input type="submit" value="Confirm & Go to Quiz 3"><br>
```

With this code in the next page I store the answers in $_SESSION

```
<?php
session_start();
$q_2 = $_POST;
if (array_key_exists('result_quiz_2',$q_2))
{
$_SESSION['result_quiz_2'] = $_POST['result_quiz_2'];
}
else $_SESSION['result_quiz_2'] = 0;
?>
```

What should i write on the final file to print out the different results?

```
foreach ()
```

doesnt work if no boxes are checked and

```
isset()
```

will print "Correct" if just one answer of the two is correct.

really appreciate for whoever can help.

Comment: foreach would work fine, if you assigned an empty array to `$_SESSION['result_quiz_2']` in your else branch, instead of 0. Don't switch data _types_ so willy-nilly! You expect this to be an array in the place where you will process this, so it should be an _empty_ array if there is no data to fill it, and not something else altogether.

Comment: Mhh, still not sure if I understood it 100%, but if you say 'foreach' is the one to use, then I´ll keep on trying with it. Thank you for stopping by and help